# Matlab allRGB image generating

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb

I`m working on script/function for school project which will generate all 24-bit RGB colors image in matlab.

I wrote something like this but it is slow (and matlab don`t like me and crashes a lot). Last time before crash it was working on for 5 days.
Here is the code:

```
a = 1;
for r = 0:255
    for g = 0:255
        for b = 0:255
            colors(a,:) = [r g b];
            a = a + 1;
        end
    end
end

colors = reshape(colors, [4096, 4096, 3]);

colors = uint8(colors);
imshow(colors);
imwrite(colors, 'generated.png');
```

Is there any faster approach to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the three columns separately using `repmat`/`repelem` and then concatenate them.

```
colors = [repelem((0:255).',256^2),...
          repmat([repelem((0:255).',256) repmat((0:255).',256,1)],256,1)];
```

Comment: The result is 2D. As mentioned in the question, the result should be 3D.

Comment: @OmG This is the vectorisation of the OP's loops. The rest of what the OP is doing remains the same.

Comment: I know, but how does OP know that?!

Comment: That seems obvious. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally a good idea to preallocate large matrices to speed up code. With your current implementation, the size of `colors` grows one row every iteration which requires a lot memory allocation resources. Try to define your matrix with

```
colors = zeros(2^24, 3);
```

at the beginning of your code. To save memory and time, you can even define the matrix as `uint8` from the beginning instead of converting it afterwards

```
colors = zeros(2^24, 3, 'uint8');
```